# Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method bov.b while loading google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

I am developing an android application, in which I need to show google maps.

but map is not loading instead of showing a white screen.

In logcat the error is Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method bov.b

I have included all properties in manifest file.

Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.pgi.routviewer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.pgi.routviewer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.pgi.routviewer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC3-blwKU7GgsARUaPNPXXVOMZPvixetKk" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" >
    </meta-data>
</application>
```

My Java class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Please help me..